# *.out file created using .sh file in Docker is not working in Mac terminal

Tags: c, bash, docker, gcc, zsh

I have an `online c program compiler` that is using the `Docker` system. So once I type the code, it will save as a `*.c` file and it will be compiled using a `*.sh` file. The output is a `*.out` file.

I am using the below command to compile the `*.c` file in the `.sh` file

```
gcc -o result.out $files -lm  
compileCxxTestgen test c
compileCxxTestgen eval c
```

This file is successfully created and I can get the output from another `*.sh` file in the same `Docker`.

**Now if I copy the same file and run in my Mac machine, I am getting below errors**

**for zsh**

> zsh: exec format error: ./result.out

**for bash**

> bash: ./result.out: cannot execute binary file

May I know why this is happening? How can I run the file in my local? Please help.

**Note:** The docker is now running in my local. So everything is happening in the same Mac machine

Comment: a program compiled on linux will not run on a mac

Comment: @pm100, Thanks for the reply. I am using the `Docker Desktop` in my mac and all the execution is happening locally. Still this will be an issue?

Comment: Docker emulates Linux — not macOS.  The code will be for Linux.  Run `file result.out` in the Docker image and on macOS — compare that with what you get for a program such as `/bin/sh` on macOS (or a program of your own that you compiled and can run on macOS).  The file type will be different; it won't work on macOS.